# IEnumerator Issue

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

I would like to enumerate through a menu, but i cant seem to get all the way down to the children.

***My model looks like this.***

```
public class Menu : IEnumerable<Menu>
{
    public new IEnumerable<Menu> Children { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<Menu> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new MenuEnumerator(this);
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class MenuEnumerator : IEnumerator<Menu>
{
    private readonly Menu _menu;

    public MenuEnumerator(Menu menu)
    {
        _menu = menu;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (this.Current == null)
        {
            this.Current = this._menu;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {

    }

    public Menu Current { get; set; }

    object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Current = null;
    }
}
```

***My menu structure***

```
public static IEnumerable<Menu> GetMenuStructure()
{
    return new Menu
    {
        Children = new List<Menu>
        {
            new Menu
            {
                PkLinkId = 2,
                FkParentLinkId = null,
                Target = "_self",
                Text = "Company",
                Children = new List<Menu>()
                {
                    new Menu()
                    {
                        PkLinkId = 4,
                        FkParentLinkId = 2,
                        Target = "_self",
                        Text = "Add A New Company",

                    },
                    new Menu()
                    {
                        PkLinkId = 27,
                        FkParentLinkId = 2,
                        Target = "_self",
                        Text = "Basic Company Information",
                    },
                }
            },
            new Menu()
            {
                PkLinkId = 5,
                FkParentLinkId = null,
                Target = "_self",
                Text = "Bureau",

                Children = new List<Menu>()
                {
                    new Menu()
                    {
                        PkLinkId = 31,
                        FkParentLinkId = 5,
                        Target = "_self",
                        Text = "Admin",
                    },
                    new Menu()
                    {
                        PkLinkId = 76,
                        FkParentLinkId = 5,
                        Target = "_self",
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

With each iteration i would like to go into the `MoveNext` function so that i can do some security checks on the `menuitem` but i can never get the child values.

I know i can use linq to do this, but my idea is to split the security code checks so that i don't pollute my foreach statement.

```
foreach (var menuItem in menu)
{

}
```

Having a hard time explaining my issue and what i would like to accomplish

Comment: Are you looking for [`yield return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)?

Comment: Why not just make `MenuEnumerator` a wrapper around the enumerator returned by `Children.GetEnumerator()`? Forward all calls.

Comment: You want to return menu itself + all children and subchildren?

Comment: @evk, yes that sounds about right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just flatten hierarchy and enumerate through whole menu, you can do it like this:

```
public IEnumerator<Menu> GetEnumerator()
{            
    // first return self
    yield return this;
    if (Children != null) {                
        foreach (var child in Children) {
            // recursively call this same function of each child
            foreach (var subChild in child) {
                yield return subChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah perfect, i think i was trying to over complicate things